# Filter the data by joining 2 columns (strings containing comma) in R

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

I have a df

```
ID <- c('DX154','DX154','DX155','DX155','DX156','DX157','DX158','DX159') 
Country <- c('US','US','US','US')
Level <- c('Level_1A','Level_1A','Level_1B','Level_1B','Level_1A','Level_1B','Level_1B','Level_1A')
Type_A <- c('Iphone','Iphone','Android','Android','aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd')
Type_B <- c("Iphone,Ipad,Ipod,Mac","Gmail,Android,Drive,Maps","Iphone,Ipad,Ipod,Mac","Gmail,Android,Drive,Maps","ALL","ALL","ALL","ALL")
df <- data.frame(ID ,Country ,Level ,Type_A,Type_B)
```

df

```
           ID Country    Level  Type_A                   Type_B
1 DX154      US Level_1A  Iphone     Iphone,Ipad,Ipod,Mac
2 DX154      US Level_1A  Iphone Gmail,Android,Drive,Maps
3 DX155      US Level_1B Android     Iphone,Ipad,Ipod,Mac
4 DX155      US Level_1B Android Gmail,Android,Drive,Maps
5 DX156      US Level_1A     aaa                      ALL
6 DX157      US Level_1B     bbb                      ALL
7 DX158      US Level_1B     ccc                      ALL
8 DX159      US Level_1A     ddd                      ALL
```

I am trying to filer this data frame by joining the column Type_A, Type_B but not knowing how to parse the comma. Could someone please help me with this.

My Desired output is

```
        ID Country    Level  Type_A                   Type_B
1 DX154      US Level_1A  Iphone     Iphone,Ipad,Ipod,Mac
2 DX155      US Level_1B Android Gmail,Android,Drive,Maps
3 DX156      US Level_1A     aaa                      ALL
4 DX157      US Level_1B     bbb                      ALL
5 DX158      US Level_1B     ccc                      ALL
6 DX159      US Level_1A     ddd                      ALL
```

Comment: I have a doubt.  Are you filtering this rowwise or by ID?

Comment: I just made an edit. I am filtering by ID only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We group by 'ID', use `grepl`, specify the pattern by `paste`ing the 'Type_A' column (In this example, using `Type_A[1L]` should also work as the 'Type_A' elements are duplicated.  A better example would be nice) and use this to `filter` the rows.  We also use `grepl` to `filter` those elements in 'Type_B' that has no `,` from start (`^`) to end (`$`) of the string.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>%
     filter(grepl(paste(Type_A, collapse='|'),
            Type_B)|grepl('^[^,]+$', Type_B))

#     ID Country    Level  Type_A                   Type_B
#1 DX154      US Level_1A  Iphone     Iphone,Ipad,Ipod,Mac
#2 DX155      US Level_1B Android Gmail,Android,Drive,Maps
#3 DX156      US Level_1A     aaa                      ALL
#4 DX157      US Level_1B     bbb                      ALL
#5 DX158      US Level_1B     ccc                      ALL
#6 DX159      US Level_1A     ddd                      ALL
```

Comment: this is a great solution. I want to apply this to a larger dataset and return other rows that doesn't require filtering also. how do I modify this?. Because when I use this code, it returns only the rows that are used in the filter.

Comment: @Sharath  I am sorry.  Your comment is not clear.  Can you update your post with a new example with expected output.

Comment: @Sharath I updated the post.  Do you have to filter only 'ALL' elements other than the earlier rows.  Anyway, I updated with a bit more general i.e. elements that don't have any comma are also filtered.

Comment: Fantastic. It worked on my bigger dataset. Thank you so much for your help. Saved a lot of time. I am new to grep concepts and learning it. Could you just explain me what's the use of collapse=' | ' here?

Comment: No problem. This saved a lot of time.

Comment: @Sharath It is kind of like searching for either of the elements in a vector. The `|` would be similar to `OR`.  Using an example,   `grepl(paste(1:2, collapse="|"), 1:4)` which is similar to `1:4 %in% 1:2`

Comment: Okay. Got it. That was a nice explanation. I will read more on grep.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one solution.  It's kind of gimmicky, but someone will be along to give you the super clever and speedy version soon.  This does it row-wise, but Akrun's answer shows you how to do it by id only.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(row_id = 1:n()) %>%
  group_by(row_id) %>%
  filter(grepl(Type_A, Type_B) | Type_B === "ALL")
```

Comment: You could remove the `mutate` step `df %>% group_by(row_id = 1:n()) %>% filter(grepl(Type_A, Type_B))`

Comment: That's a cool trick.  Didn't know you could assign new variables within `group_by`.